# ODRefresh control calling more then once

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pull-to-refresh

I am working on ODRefresh control as pull to refresh controller. I added this in my project to refresh when user drag the table view from top. It is working fine for some view controllers. But in one view controller it is calling more than once when i drag down the table view. I don't understand why it is calling like this. I used the same code as in other view controllers. Here my code is

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let refreshControl: ODRefreshControl = ODRefreshControl.init(inScrollView: userTableView)

refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refreshAction:" , forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

}

func refreshAction(refreshControl:UIRefreshControl)
{
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    skipIndex = 0
    dataArray.removeAll()
    getDataFromDB()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

}
```

Can any one please help me to solve this.

Comment: Make sure that you have not implement it except `viewDidload`. This is not get calling from other method than `viewdidload`.

Comment: I called it only in the  viewdidload. And i am sure that it does not call from other method.